# ¿Cómo se dice "in order to soak in the culture" en español?

Tags: traducción, modismos

As the question suggests. How would you say "in order to soak in the culture".

Would you say "para calar a la cultura"?

Comment: Welcome to Spanish.SE! Could you add some context? Who wants or will or has soaked in the culture? I'm also curious as to why you've chosen "clavar" as a translation for "soak (in)". What dictionary have you checked?

Comment: As @Yay suggests, please provide more context. You can get a good grasp on how to by reading [ask] and going through the [tour]. By the way, so nice to see you here, Yay!!

Comment: Points noted for next time. I wanted to say calar instead of clavar which might have caused some confusion. I used word reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lacking a more specific context, I would say:

> Para empaparse de la cultura.

In Spanish you can use the word *[empapar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ElfsKMP)* with the following meaning:

> 5. prnl. Imbuirse de un afecto, idea o doctrina hasta penetrarse bien de ellos.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest an alternative, because I think "empaparse" is a great word, but stronger than the original.

**absorber**: absorb, take in

> Voy a hacer tal o cual cosa para absorber la cultura.

The literal word would also work well:

**conocer**: get to know

> Voy a hacer tal o cual cosa, para conocer la cultura.

Answer (score 0):

Answer with an example of context

> They lived in Costa Rica in order to soak in the culture

you can say

> Ellos vivieron en Costa Rica con el fin de aprender sobre la cultura

as @Carlos Alejo said you can use

> Ellos vivieron en Costa Rica con el fin de empaparse de la cultura

Comment: No need to repeat the previous answer. // I think you need an object with "aprender."  For example, "... con el fin de aprender algo de la cultura de Costa Rica." // I like your turn of phrase, "con el fin de".